# JavaScript Inside UpdatePanle

Tags: javascript, updatepanel, postback, fadeout

I can't get this working. I want to `fadeout` a `div` after a `postback`. This `div` is inside an `updatepanel`. I understand that because of `updatepanel` it will be a partial refresh. But within this context, how can i still use `fadeout`?

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="content_head" runat="Server">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#div_msg").delay(1500).fadeOut("slow");
        });

    </script>
</asp:Content>


<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel6" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnl_msgs" runat="server" Visible="false">
                <div id="div_msg">
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_msg" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                </div>
        </asp:Panel>

        <asp:Button ID="but_status_new" runat="server" Text="New" CssClass="new-button-flat" onclick="but_status_new_Click"/>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I am not writing any js code in `but_status_new_Click` function.

Comment: Can you please post some (only relevant) code? Both markup for the panel/div and fadeout code?

Answer (score 0):

Instead `document.ready` try using `function pageLoad` since ASP.NET AJAX has its own page lifecycle:

```
function pageLoad() {
   $("#div_msg").delay(1500).fadeOut("slow");
}
```

Oh and move reference to jQuery to ScriptManager itself

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" >
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" />
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is sorted, but how can i do the slidedown and then slideup? I am trying it but it doesn't seem to fire!

Comment: That's a separate question :) j/k. If fadeOut works that means jQuery in general works and slides should work too, check syntax and params.